# Image storage as a service

Tags: java, image, google-app-engine, seam

Google App Engine provides a image API for storing / retrieving images. We are currently not in a position to deploy our application on top of App Engine because of limitations in the java frameworks (jboss seam 2.2.0) we are using to build our j2ee application.

We would eventually want to deploy our production application on top of Google App Engine, but what are the short term options (java based open source products) which provides comparable functionality to Google App Engine's Image API and will have an easier migration path at a later point in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's not a java-based open source product but if you are talking about the Blobstore API (just for storing/retrieving images), I'd recommend replacing it with Amazon S3 : http://aws.amazon.com/s3/

It doesn't have the features of the Image Manipulation API from Google App Engine though.

Comment: Are there any other products much similar to Amazon S3's offerings

Comment: I have decided to write an abstraction layer myself, so that it will be easier for me to port this to GAE later on.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking good image storage try Bildero.